# Login screen settings icon disappeared

Tags: gdm, wayland, session

So, I used to have a login settings icon on the login screen, which would show as you type your password. See the bottom right icon here: (mine use to have 2 entries, not 3.)

[image: gdm3]

I tried a Wayland session twice (instead of the usual x11) and my desktop failed to come up.

So I thought I would reboot my machine. Now, on the login screen, I never see the settings icon again.

What caused the settings icon (that lets me choose between wayland/x11) to disappear?

Do failed wayland sessions disable themselves from this menu?

**OS**: 22.04

**kernel**: 5.15.0

**GPU**: GTX 1650

**nvidia driver**: 470.141.03

**gdm3**: 42.0-1ubuntu7

## UPDATE

It happened again, this time on 22.04-1 on Intel IGP.

I can only launch xorg, and cannot launch wayland because the gear icon has disappeared. Moving the mouse to the corner does not help.

Why can't I see the gear icon?

Comment: and when you move your mouse over to the lower-right corner, it doesn't come up?

Comment: @Esther I tried installing nvidia driver 520, which fixed the problem. If it ever happens again, I will try the mouse solution. Thanks!